# Edit images in a Drupal node programmatically

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to import data into a Drupal 8 everyday and I'm blocked at the point where I need to update images. So I've got a Image field which contains unlimited images.

When I first import images, I'm creating them and adding them to the node field_images field. The adding is working.

```
$entity = Node::create(
 [...,
  field_images => [$file1],
  ...
 ]);
```

When there's a node update, I need to replace every changed value of this node. This code is working perfectly

```
$node = Node::load(1);
$node->set('field_images',[$file2]);
$node->save();
```

Now this doesn't work when I enable translations as it edits only the default value.
See this debugger image when I reload this updated node:

[image]

How could I update all translations too ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
     'field_image' => 
      [
        'target_id' => $values['image'][0],
        'alt' => $values['title'],
      ],
```

Comment: $file1 is already loaded and contains what you wrote. I said the insert was working :) That's just the translation part, not working. I just updated to drupal 8.2.1 and still there're some problems, maybe caused by drupal ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$node->field_images->de->target_id = $file->id();
```